# GDB step into Dynamic linker(ld.so) code

Tags: c, linux, linker, gdb, glibc

I wanted to step into the code of ld.so whenever it will be used in my normal `c` code.
I am trying to code flow through GDB in the [TUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115540/gdb-split-view-with-code) mode where you can see both source code and assembly as you step over the code.

For this I also installed  `libc-dbg` `binutils-source` package from ubuntu package manager.
GDB can find the debug symbols for the `ld.so` itself and I can step at the instruction level that is using `si` but I cant step at the source level as GDB is not able to find the source for `ld.so` and shows `NO Source Available`.

How can I make GDB find the source for `ld.so` so that I can also see which line in the `ld.so` source is actually being executed.

I am using `Ubuntu 12.10` 64bit with `GCC 4.8.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've libc's source code available, you can add sources to gdb's source path with `dir` command: [Source_Path](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html)

Edit: To debug libc related files (in a Ubuntu distro) you would need to:

1. Get libc's debug information by installing libc6-dbg packet.
2. Get libc's source code by enabling source repositories (by running `software-sources` and and checking "enable source code repositories") and running `apt-get source libc6`
3. Add libc's debug information into LD_LIBRARY_PATH: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug gdb <application>`
4. Add full path to c file to gdb's source path, this is: `dir directory_path_libc_source/stdio-common`

Comment: I tried downloading the source through apt but got this error apt-get source libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'eglibc' as source package instead of 'libc6'
E: Unable to find a source package for eglibc. So I did a wget the libc source for the version I have. I set the source_path using set directories absolute path to the  root of the libc source. But I still can not see the source code for libc in GDB while stepping

Comment: @abhi This means that you miss enabling source repositories. You can enable them from "software sources" (you can reach it from "software center"'s edit menu or, from command line, running `sofware-sources`), and you will see a "enable source code repositories"

Comment: I corrected the apt-get source issue as you directed and downloaded the libc6 source in a directory. Started the gdb with simple test program to debug which had only one printf() and on stepping the code I still cant see the source. See the screen shot after i step on the printf() https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z8btk672vfaxot/gdb.png

Comment: @abhi Have you added libc's source directory with `dir` command? I mean, from your capture, it seems that it's not in gdb's source patch. Can you also try running `info sources` to check it?

Comment: This is exactly what I did:  1. gdb ./test -> dir directory_path_libc_source(the path is shown in show dir) the set a breakpoint before printf() and run. On hitting Breakpoint I did info sources (https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7b2rcysxqoexju/gdb1.png) stepped but cant see the code.                                                 On hitting printf() it says _printf (format=0x400594 "ABHI") at printf.c:30
30 printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
34 in printf.c
(gdb) s
30 in printf.c

Comment: @abhi Have you added libc's debuginfor files into LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: I tried with adding /usr/lib/debug/lib/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it also did not help. Am I missing something else? Thanks for answering so many times.

Comment: @abhi OK, I've tested and I think I know the problem. You should add full path to c file, this is: dir directory_path_libc_source/stdio-common. This together with LD_LIBRARY_PATH when you run gdb: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug gdb <application>

Answer (score 0):

Download the Glibc source and path the same with gdb before debugging. Check this [ubuntu blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dbx/entry/gnu_debuglink_or_debugging_system)

Comment: I tried the command given for gdb in the link you provided and gave it the path of the dir where I have the glibc source. I used a test program which had only a main with printf("ASAS") but on reaching the printf() it did not step into the printf() code in libc. Am I missing something